# How to connect AWS Managed Microsoft AD in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-directory-services

I've configured the AWS Managed Microsoft Directory Service through the AWS console and I've  researched on npm modules that connects AWS Managed Microsoft AD in nodejs
But I didn't find any to connect the AWS Managed AD in nodejs to authenticate at the Login page.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the activedirectory npm package